# Dependency was not found using vuex

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I am following an online tutorial in which he uses vuex. I installed vuex as can be seen in my package.json dependencies.

```
{
  "name": "blabla",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "blablaa",
  "author": "blabla",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "start": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.4.2",
    "vue-router": "^2.7.0",
    "vuetify": "^0.16.9",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-add-filehash": "^6.9.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.0.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.3",
    "opn": "^5.1.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.5.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

In my store folder, I have an index.js file where I am creating my vuex in this manner

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.store({
   //my code here
})
```

Then in my main.js under src I am importing it like this

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import './stylus/main.styl'

import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import { store } from '/.store/index.js'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
This dependency was not found:

* /.store/index.js in ./src/main.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save /.store/index.js
```

I have no idea why I am getting this. What would cause this error? I am new to webdev and not using a compiler so not sure how I can use a debugger here either. Would appreciate if someone could guide me on how to find the error if not the error itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think:

`import { store } from '/.store/index.js'`

Should be:

`import { store } from './store/index.js'`